# React Native without android studio environement on windows 10

Tags: android, react-native

i'm new to React Native, so i've followed tutorial; i've created the app from `create-react-native-app` , putting some functionality and tested with expo  and it worked well. But now i'm passing to react native with native code by using `npm run eject` and choosed the bare react-native but not the expo, the ejection was successful. But when i run the command `react-native run-android` i got this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlGEl.png)

I'm not using android studio but only the sdk manager, already installed jdk and i've installed android package for android 5 to 9; the environement path is:

user variable:

JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

ANDROID_HOME: `C:\Users\Necrometal XD\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

Path: `C:\Users\Necrometal XD\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools; C:\Users\Necrometal XD\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

system variable:

ANDROID_HOME: `C:\Users\Necrometal XD\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

ANDROID_SDK_HOME: `C:\Users\Necrometal XD\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

Path: `C:\Users\Necrometal XD\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools; C:\Users\Necrometal XD\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;`

my device is connected, i've already checked with `adb devices`

result:

List of devices attached

f6077430        device

but the error persist :/ i don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it :) 
I'm on Xiaomi Mi 8 and didn't saw that my developper mode was disabled after updated the version, so just needed to enabled the debugging mode and installation via usb